# UserForm Freezes after using Button

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a CommandButton in a UserFrom that does something like this:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton_Click()

     If (ModuleExists("myModule") = False) Then
         MsgBox stringAlert
         Exit Sub 'This line does not freezes it.
     End If

     inputsToValidate = True 'This is a public variable
     validarInput 'This method validates the userform inputs, if all OK inputsToValidate = False

     If inputsToValidate Then
         Exit Sub 'This line freezes the userform. The code actually continues, but when it does exits the sub it freezes.
     End If

     DoThings

     Unload InterpolateCurveForm

End Sub
```

As you can see in my comments the code works except when it enters into the "If inputsToValidate Then" statement. If it happens, the code actually executes the Exit Sub line, but after that it freezes.

validarInputs is a Private Sub that shows messages if any input is wrong. If everything is Ok no message is shown and it changes Public variable inputsToValidate to False

Comment: Consider commenting out some stuff one by one (like commenting out `validarInput` and stet `inputsToValidate = False`, to figure out when it does not freeze anymore. So you figure out in which part of the code your issues is.

Answer (score 1):

I tried changing the public variable to a local variable and then changing validarInputs to a private function so inputsToValidate is defined like this: `inputsToValidate = validarInputs`

This is working properly now.

Comment: That's definitely the better way to let the function return a value than using global variables. Also giving `inputsToValidate` as a `ByRef` parameter would be a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative way you can do :

```
....

    If inputsToValidate = False Then
        DoThings
        Unload InterpolateCurveForm
    End If

End Sub
```